# How do I mount one Google Drive folder with images only onto Google Colab and iterate through it?

Tags: python, machine-learning, computer-vision, google-colaboratory

I have a folder of images I extracted for a computer-vision project, but don't know how to mount it onto Google Colab and iterate through the folder. I have a function I need to apply to each image inside the folder, but don't know how to get the images.

I've tried looking for resources but haven't found anything helpful to my situation, because most of them were for unzipping files that were not images. Can you please help me out? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the OpenCV library for this.

```
from google.colab import drive
import os
import cv2
```

First you need to change the current working directory to your image folder directory.

```
os.chdir("/content/drive/MyDrive/yourfolder")
```

You can iterate through every image, apply your function to them and save the final version like this:

```
for file in os.listdir():
  img = cv2.imread(file)
  
  result = myfunction(img)
  
  cv2.imwrite(file, result)
```